# run regasm.exe on a .net com class

Tags: c#, com, installshield, regasm

how to run regasm on a .net com visible class from installshield? I can manually register by calling the regasm.exe on the dll but when i set the '.net Com Interop' to 'Yes' in the installshield project i get an error -6210.

Comment: Is there any other detail with the error message?

Comment: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107824

Comment: Thanks Chris your answer helped me. I added a .Net dll to an older Installshield project and was getting the 6210 error. It was because IS was using regasm.exe from the 1.1 folder instead of 2.0. Just had to update setting in Tools | Options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because the version of the .net used to build the DLL was latest than the one specified under Tools>Options>/ .net tab. When I updated the .net folder to the latest one there, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's a problem finding a dependency of the COM DLL.

See if one of these links helps:

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-167698.html

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107824

Answer (score 0):

You usually want to avoid running regasm during installation.  If InstallShield doesn't know about the modifications to the system, it can't guarantee that it will clean up properly.  If you can't get IS to extract the information from the links in the other answer, you might use the /regfile option of regasm to get the keys and add them to IS.